# Create n rows up to highest value in column for each unique client

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this data in my postgresSQL db.

| id | client_id | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |

I want to create multiple entries for each unique client corresponding to the number in the num column. For example to complete this task for the above column I would have.

| id | client_id | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |

Filling in all numbers between 0 and num with new entries. I'd prefer to do this in a single command or loop versus the manually adding entries method that I know. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Beat me to the edit. Didn't even notice I had done that haha. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by joining with [`generate_series`](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/generate-series/) using `num` as the max value. Use `row_number` to generate an ID for each row.

```
select
  row_number() over() as id,
  client_id,
  g.num as num
from clients
cross join generate_series(1, clients.num) as g(num)
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/6i2QQthn)

Comment: Appreciate you linking the article. Had no idea about this feature.

Comment: @Colourised You're welcome! It's so useful I'm astonished more databases have not adopted it.

Comment: The A,B style join makes me want to strangle a kitten

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Cross join to the rescue!

Comment: Yay! Now the only trick is getting the `id` values right.

Comment: This solution was great, only thing I changed was setting id, I used next_val('id_seq') as id to set my id as I wasn't creating an entirely new table but inserting into an existing one.

Comment: @Colourised An auto-incrementing primary key would remove the need to use the sequence manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `RECURSIVE` query, that decrements your `num` index by one at each iteration, and stop when this value is equal to 1.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, client_id, num FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, client_id, num-1 
    FROM cte
    WHERE num-1 > 0
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY id, client_id, num
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kGwRGxoxecCx5A5AaZvquk/1).

Comment: Or `WHERE num>1` if you will.

Comment: That's useful for databases which do not have `generate_series`.

Comment: `generate_series` is rather interesting, would you say that most/all problems that involve recursive queries could be carried out with this function?

Comment: Just ones that generate a series of values. ;)